# My Update Command Not Working To Update Database From DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Here is my code to update the database from datagridview if any body have the answer please tell me.

```
try
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbSex.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbFeesAmount.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbFeesStatus.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbSex.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Date.Text)) { MessageBox.Show("Please Input data."); return; }
         Update(lblDI.Text);
         Reset();
         this.BindGrid();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _Doesn't Work_ exactly? You get any exception or error message? What `Update` and `Reset` methods do exactly? Show their definition as well.

Comment: A little hint in case you are working with others on the same code: the standard way to abbreviate Create Read Update Delete operations is CRUD, not CURD.

Comment: @grek40        Thanks for your hint,

Answer (score 0):

I Done some edits to the code and now it's working fine for me .     i forgot to declare the   sda.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();

```
private static void CurdOperation()
    {
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source="
            + System.IO.Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "MyDB.sdf"));
        sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
        SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblFees";
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

        SqlCeCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(sda);
        sda.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
        sda.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
        sda.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
    }
    #endregion
try
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbSex.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbFeesAmount.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbFeesStatus.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbSex.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Date.Text)) { MessageBox.Show("Please Input data."); return; }
         Update(lblDI.Text);
         Reset();
         this.BindGrid();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Now it Works.